# CNAME-Alias in Terraform / Route53

Tags: dns, terraform, amazon-route53

I have an existing dns entry like 
 "something.domainmanagedbyroute53.de.";"3600";"IN";"CNAME";"";"server.some-external-domain.de"

and want to express this ALIAS in Terraform for Route53.

Under https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/route53_record.html
I got the impression that I have to use something like

```
resource "aws_elb" "main" {
     name               = "foobar-terraform-elb"
     availability_zones = ["us-east-1c"] 

     listener {
       instance_port     = 80
       instance_protocol = "http"
       lb_port           = 80
       lb_protocol       = "http"
     }
   }

   resource "aws_route53_record" "www" {
     zone_id = "${aws_route53_zone.primary.zone_id}"
     name    = "example.com"
     type    = "A"

     alias {
       name                   = "${aws_elb.main.dns_name}"
       zone_id                = "${aws_elb.main.zone_id}"
       evaluate_target_health = true
     }
   }
```

However I am wondering where the target goes...

Comment: "`CNAME` to some external domain" is different from "`ALIAS` to internal AWS resource" , you first have to decide which one do you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route53 aliases are a special mechanism that allows you to include a recordset in your zone that is taken from a recordset in another zone. However, it only works if the recordset you want to alias is *also* in a Route53 zone, restricted to the following zones:

- The same Route53 zone that the record is being created in.
- The AWS-provided Route53 zones for services such as Amazon S3, Cloudfront, etc.

Note that it isn't possible to alias from a non-Route53 zone, and it's *also* impossible to alias from some other Route53 zone in your own account.

The example you shared shows the way alias records are used with Terraform: some other service (an elastic load balancer, in this case) exposes both its DNS name *and* the id of the Route53 zone that DNS name belongs to, and you specify both of those in the `alias` block.

The effect of that resource is that if Route53 gets a query for (in this case) `A` records at `example.com`, it will then internally query the other Route53 zone given in `aws_elb.main.zone_id` for the hostname given in `aws_elb.main.dns_name` and return whatever IP addresses are indicated there.

Neither of the hostnames you showed in your example seem to belong directly to an AWS service that offers a Route53 zone, so you can't use aliases to meet this use-case. You must use `CNAME` records instead.